# Shiny Input Output Text

Tags: input, output, shiny

I have this in my code

```
server:
output$print_amount <- renderText({"1000"}) 

ui:
 column(3, uiOutput("print_amount", label = "", value = 0))
```

Sometimes IU want to fill manually and other times by my code. But doing like this I can't, as  the textbox is disabled

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found teh answer:

SERVER

```
updateNumericInput(session, "print_amount", value = 1000)
```

UI

```
column(3, numericInput("print_amount", label = "", value = 0)),
```